# Why is the Object treated as an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In the below code, **obj** is an **object**, but why is its values are accessed using **[key ] like array** instead of a **dot followed by its key**?

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var val = obj[keys[i]];
    // use val
}
```

Comment: actually, arrays are objects, so it's arrays that are being treated like an object.  Arrays can be thought of as objects that have numerical keys - 0, 1, 2, 3... and so on.  They also have various methods on the prototype to use above normal objects - .splice, .slice etc

Comment: Because the language allows it?

Comment: It's [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation), it allows you to use dynamic keys (unlike dot-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the Object treated as an Array?

It isn't.

[Properties of objects can be accessed](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors) by dot notation (`object.identifier`) or square bracket notation (`object[expression]`).

Arrays are a type of object. They have special behaviour for properties where the name is an integer.

An identifier can't start with a number, so to access a property where the name is an integer you *must* use square bracket notation. This means that *most* properties accessed on arrays use square bracket notation.

It **doesn't** mean that square bracket notation is particular to arrays.

```js
const object = {
  "3": "three",
  "four": 4
};

console.log(object[3]);
const three = 3;
console.log(object[three]);
console.log(object.four);
console.log(object["four"]);
// console.log(object.3); // this errors because an identifier cannot start with a number
```

Comment: Might be worth linking to the [Property Accessors section of the ECMAScript standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors)